# Node.js + MongoDB checking if the email already exists in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I get stucked while writing my website at this point.

There is a function:

```
/* check if email already exists in database */
function validateEmailAccessibility(email){

   User.findOne({email: email}).then(function(result){
        if(result!=null){

        }
   });
}
```

And the question is how the hell I have to return the false when it already exists?

I've tried to do this like that, but obviously second condition is checked until the variable temp is set to false.

```
/* check if email already exists in database */
function validateEmailAccessibility(email){
   var temp;
   User.findOne({email: email}).then(function(result){
        if(result!=null){
           temp = false;
        }
   });
   if(temp === false) return false;
}
```

I have no idea what should I do.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to return a promise in `validateEmailAccessibility`:

```js
function validateEmailAccessibility(email){

   return User.findOne({email: email}).then(function(result){
        return result !== null;
   });
}
```

And somewhere in your code:

```
validateEmailAccessibility(email).then(function(valid) {
  if (valid) {
    alert("Email is valid");
  } else {
    alert("Email already used");
  }
});
```